# Python Counting Line not giving correct number

Tags: python, python-2.7, count

I have a .csv file where I add a column to the beginning.
I then need to change the encoding for a certain tool to read properly

The file has around 9,800 lines.When I count the lines before and after I add the column, I get the same number. But, when I count after I change the encoding, I get less. The strange part is that when I open the file, I can see that all the lines are there.

Here is the code:

```
file = open("ob_input.csv")
outfile = open("ob_output.csv", "w")
outfile.write("COLUMNS\n")
print "\n*************** Adding Date Column ***************"
date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S,")
i1 = 0
for line in file:
    i1 = i1 + 1
    if "Asset ID,CI Type" in line:
        pass
    else:
        newline = date + line
        outfile.write(newline)

file.close()
outfile.close()
time.sleep(2)
print "Done! Total lines: %d" % i1
print "\n**************** Changing Encoding ***************"
sourceEncoding = "utf-8"
targetEncoding = "utf-8-sig"
source = open("ob_output.csv")
target = open("ob_finle.csv", "w")
target.write(unicode(source.read(), sourceEncoding).encode(targetEncoding))

i2 = sum(1 for line in open('ob_finle.csv'))
print "Done! Total lines: %d" % i2
```

The output I get is:

```
*************** Adding Date Column ***************
Done! Total lines: 9741

**************** Changing Encoding ***************
Done! Total lines: 9729
```

The 9741 is correct. When I open the file after the encoding change, I get 9741 lines. I don't know why it's counting less.

What I am doing is making sure that after changing the file, I won't miss data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open your file with the target encoding:

```
from io import open

i2 = sum(1 for line in open('ob_finle.csv', encoding=targetEncoding))
```

Using `io.open` allows the keyword argument `encoding` and makes it work in Python 2 and 3 because:

Python 3:

```
>>> import io
>>> io.open is  open
True
```

Comment: When i use "open" i get this error for line "outfile.write(newline)":
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 109-110: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Im sorry, im slightly new to python

Comment: Ok. You need to make all strings unicode in Python 2.`u'mystring'`.

Comment: Or just use Python 3. :)

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much for the help! :)